# An arithmetic sequence has first term $a_{1} = 1$ and fourth term $a_{4} = 10$. How many terms of this sequence must be added to get 1717?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

An arithmetic sequence has first term $a_{1} = 1$ and fourth term $a_{4} = 10$. How many terms of this sequence must be added to get 1717?

I tried:

$ d = 3$ since the sequence could be $1, 4, 7, 10...$

$1717 = 1 + (n-1)3$

$n = 573$

Comment: Be careful; the question asks you to add the terms of the sequence until you  get 1717, not where 1717 appears in the sequence. Do you know how to sum terms of an arithmetic sequence?

Comment: The sequence not only *could* be that sequence; that is the *only* arithmetic sequence with those two terms (since the common difference of the sequence has to be $(10-1)/3=3$).

Comment: @Cataline Is there a formula ?

Comment: There are two main formulas for the [sum of an arithmetic sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Formulas_at_a_Glance): $$S_n=\frac n2(2a+(n-1)d)$$ $$S_n=\frac n2(a_1+a_n)$$

Comment: Thank you for the formulas, I wasn't aware of the first one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expression gives the nth number of the sequence, not the sum of the first n numbers. The sum $S$ of the first m numbers is given by $S=\sum_{0}^m 1+(n-1)3=\sum_{0}^m -2+3n=-2m+\frac{3m(m+1)}{2}$ And if we put $-2m+\frac{3m(m+1)}{2}=1717$ We get $m=34$